# How to create arrow down/up in css

Tags: html, css

How can I create a arrow point `down`/`up` in css?

I tried to build it from div:

```css
.triangle_down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #2f2f2f;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle_down"></div>
```

This is the result:[image].

But I tried to build something like this:[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: more modern approach is use `content` property of css in `::before` or `::after` pseudo class. There are lots of icon/symbol fonts available that you can use to populate the content to achieve what you want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My proposal is:

```css
.triangle_down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #2f2f2f;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  float: left;
}
.triangle_down1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-right: 0.2em solid black;
  border-top: 0.2em solid black;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1.0em;
}
 .triangle_up1 {
   position: relative;
   top: -5px;
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   border-right: 0.2em solid black;
   border-top: 0.2em solid black;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   margin-right: 0.5em;
   margin-left: 1.0em;
 }
```

```html
<div id="dialog1" class="triangle_down"></div>
<div id="dialog2" class="triangle_down1"></div>
<div id="dialog3" class="triangle_up1"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

What you want is a chevron, not an arrow. Pure CSS solution:

```
.chevron::before {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.15em 0.15em 0 0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.45em;
    left: 0.15em;
    top: 0.15em;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0.45em;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5f4h787/)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use icons you can use ::before and ::after pseudo-class.

This is one of the various way you can get an arrow in pure CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}

.arrow::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
  left: 14px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

You can find an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/f3qpujpL/2/

Answer (score 5):

```css
#uparrow:before {
    content: '\276F';
}

#downarrow:before {
    content: '\276E';
}

#uparrow, #downarrow {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span id="uparrow"></span><span id="downarrow"></span>
```

You can include unicode characters like that, which are used by pretty much any system nowadays. Check out how it looks here: https://jsfiddle.net/mcdbu2pj/2/

Simply find the correct unicode characters you want. It won't matter which direction they're in, as you can just rotate them (like I did). Remember to set their display property to `inline-block`!

Comment: This is an arrow, he want's a chevron I believe.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda Did you check my edit? That's a chevron.

Comment: I did not. This is probably the preferred solution. Is there any way to customize it?

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda Customize as in?

Comment: Shape, thickness, height, etc. I mean they probably don't need it, I was just curious if it's possible.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda By adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` you can reduce the thickness A BIT, but it's not a whole lot. Other than.. not really. As far as I've read, you cannot stretch these :(

Comment: @Snorlax how you got two upvotes for this is beyond me, however, it is still not a chevron lol

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Is yours a CSS solution? No. Mine is :)

Comment: Its like if the OP asked for a square and you drew them a circle, so what, it is still not correct lol

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith "how to create arrow down/up in css" - Is mine an arrow? Yep. Does mine look like his? Yep. Is mine purely CSS? Yep. Where did I fail?

Comment: you can use any unicode, there's a lot of arrow-ish things, including chevrons of different thicknesses...

Comment: @dandavis I wasn't able to find a thin one like OPs unfortunately.

Comment: you can rotate `&#10093;` or `&#10095;` as needed. (sorry for the non-css code format)

Comment: @dandavis I have not been able to rotate them properly. Can you edit my jsfiddle with yours and rotate them?

Comment: @dandavis Figured it out. Their display has to be set to inline-block! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Right arrow: <i class="arrow right"></i></p>
<p>Left arrow: <i class="arrow left"></i></p>
<p>Up arrow: <i class="arrow up"></i></p>
<p>Down arrow: <i class="arrow down"></i></p>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It provides the most simple and clean solution and pointedly illustrates how to generate right, left, up, and down arrows using CSS transforms and borders in a clear and compact manner. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As simple as it gets:

```css
.up,
.down {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
<div class="down"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of arrow you need, there is a very simple approach using HTML symbol codes.   For instance I used `&#x2191;` for an arrow pointing upwards.
I found it here [HTML Symbols](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/)